# postgresql - bytea v jsonb vs xml

Tags: postgresql

Would be needing to store in a field either an XML or JSON or could be other types as well in the future in postgresql.  From the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html, I understand we have xml, json, jsonb, bytea datatypes.  There's really need to query each by tag or field, just need to dump the file to store and fetch it as a whole, so I'm thinking of bytea instead.  Any significant performance on it?  Am I on the right track.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both types you want to store are made of character data (and not binary data), the best choice would be `text`

Comment: Can you explain why `text` is best choice?

Comment: Well, JSON and XML are both string/text values. And `text` is the natural choice for that